# Removing a list containing the same elements from a list in Python

Tags: python, list

Is there a straightforward way to remove a list containing all elements the same instead of specifying the actual location? For example, `A[1]` has to be removed because all the elements are the same?

```
A=[[[1],[2],[2]],[[3],[3],[3]],[[4],[5],[4]]]
print(A)

A.remove(A[1])
print(A)
```

The output is and should be

```
[[[1],[2],[2]],[[4],[5],[4]]]
```

Comment: Are you asking how to remove duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a list comprehension here:

```py
A = [[[1],[2],[2]],[[3],[3],[3]],[[4],[5],[4]]]
output = [x for x in A if min(x) != max(x)]
print(output)  # [[[1], [2], [2]], [[4], [5], [4]]]
```

We can identify a sublist as candidate for being removed by checking if the min and max values be the same.  If those two values are *not* the same, then we retain the sublist.

Comment: Won't work if only one item is in the list which will make it both the minimum and the maximum

Comment: I want to print ```A``` after removing the ```output```.

Comment: @ThePyGuy The OP did not give any indication that there might be one-element lists.  But, assuming there were, I would assume that such lists should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can count number of equal items in list with list.count method.
Considering that all elements of the A cannot be empty you can filter them like this.

```
filtered = [el for el in A if el.count(el[0]) != len(el)]
```

Or to be sure that code will not throw the IndexError on empty items, you can check the length of an item.

```
filtered = [el for el in A if len(el) and el.count(el[0]) != len(el)]
```

This approach will also works for strings and other types.